# How to use hasMany which has belongsTo in the child

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have database relation like below

[image]

I want to get shop data with their products which each product has their category. If we define it using Eloquent ORM in Laravel, shop `hasMany` products `belongsTo` productCategory.

I can get the data of shop with their products using `hasMany`, but I can't get the productCategory of each products. Does anyone know how to get the productCategory of each product?

Shop model:

```
class Shop extends Model
{    
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Procuct model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function shop() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory');
    }
}
```

Product category model:

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Shop controller to get the data:

```
class ShopController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Shop $shop)
    {
        $products = $shop->products()->get();
        return view('pages.shop-detail.index')->with('shop', $shop)->with('products', $products);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add to the question the query you have made so far and the names of the relationships.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sure, I have add the model

Comment: Where you can't get the productCategory of each product? I guess you are trying to show it in the view? Can you show us how?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the all the products of a shop in the view, but I need the product category too of each product card @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Which version of Laravel is this? It actually matters for the Eloquent querying of relationships. For instance if it's 5.x* selectRaw might be the road you need to go. All depends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [One To Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) Relationships:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed by the name of the primary key column. However, if the foreign key on the `Product` model is not `category_id`, you should pass the custom key name as the second argument to the `belongsTo` method:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'product_category_id');
    }
}
```

Then in the view, loop over shop products an show the name of the product and the name of the product category:

```
<h3>Shop: {{ $shop->name }}</h3>
@foreach ($shop->products as $product)
    <p>Product: {{ $product->name }}</p>
    <small>Category: {{ $product->category->name }}</small>
@endforeach
```

But...

Doing the query in the way you had it in the question you'll have an N + 1 problem when you loop on products in the view.

Avoid the model binding in your controller to eager load the relationships and return just the shop, the products and category will be eager loaded on the `Shop` object:

```
class ShopController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $shop = Shop::with('products', 'products.category')->find($id);

        return view('pages.shop-detail.index')->with('shop', $shop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It's work using your query and also I have add the `product_category_id` too in the product model, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Doing the query that way will avoid an N + 1 problem when you loop the view. It would work the way you had it in the question, but it would be intense for the DB. I think the answer to the question problem is to explicitly declaring the foreign key in the relationship.